# How to check a type variable is a ambiguous type?

Tags: haskell

I'm reading *Thinking with Types*, chapter4 has a question that:

```hs
type family AlwaysUnit a where
    AlwaysUnit a = ()

{- which a is ambiguous type? -}
AlwaysUnit a -> a
b -> AlwaysUnit a -> b
Show a => AlwaysUnit a -> String
```

I know that `Show a => AlwaysUnit a -> String` has ambiguous type, but I want to know why `AlwaysUnit a -> a` has no ambiguous type? I cann't implement `AlwaysUnit a -> a` this type signature into a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`type` aliases (and `type family` aliases by extension) do not create new types. They literally *alias* to the thing on the right hand side. In your case, there's only one branch in the `type family`, and it matches all types, so it will always be taken. So `AlwaysUnit a` is *always* equal to `()`. Not isomorphic, not sort-of-similar, but *equal*. That is, these three types

```
AlwaysUnit a -> a
b -> AlwaysUnit a -> b
Show a => AlwaysUnit a -> String
```

are entirely equal (again, not isomorphic, but a very strong form of equality) to these three

```
() -> a
b -> () -> b
Show a => () -> String
```

In the first example, we still have an `a`, so it's not ambiguous. In the second example, `a` is *completely* eliminated, so it's as though it wasn't there in the first place. Haskell is happy to quietly ignore the "unused" variable. In the third example, however, we have a variable `a` that is used in the constraint (the thing on the left of the `=>`) but not in the type proper. That's going to create a problem whenever we try to call that function, and short of [`TypeApplications`](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/type-application) I don't think there's a good way to resolve that conflict.

Note that things would be more complicated if `AlwaysUnit` had multiple cases or did some pattern matching against its type. You can end up in a situation where none of the cases match or where GHC can't decide whether the case should match or not, and it will refuse to simplify. In that case, you'll end up with an `AlwaysUnit a` that *doesn't* simplify in your type.

> I cann't implement `AlwaysUnit a -> a` this type signature into a function.

That's a good intuition, but there are a couple of problems. First, you can always implement any function in Haskell.

```
f :: AlwaysUnit a -> a
f _ = undefined
```

So, if we're allowing [bottom types](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Wider_Theory), then every type in Haskell is inhabited. And even if we're *not* allowing bottom types, then "can I implement this function" and "is the type ambiguous" are entirely different questions. For instance, I can't implement a function of type `Int -> Void` without resorting to bottom types, since `Int` is clearly inhabited and `Void` is clearly not. But it's not an ambiguous type. It's a perfectly well-defined but empty function type.

Comment: Slight terminology thing: I think instead of "allowing bottom types" you mean something like "allowing bottom in types". You're talking about bottom *values* in a particular type, not a bottom *type*. (But it could also be this is a common usage that I just haven't seen elsewhere.)

Answer (score 4):

Of course, you can't implement `AlwaysUnit a -> a` when `a` is an unbound type variable (without cheating by using ⊥). But that's not what the question asks. Ambiguous types are asking, if the compiler encounters an expression with this type, can it infer a type for `a` from context?

Suppose we have

```
exercise1 :: AlwaysUnit a -> a
exercise1 = undefined

main = putStrLn $ exercise1 ()
```

Can you tell what type has been chosen for `a` at this call site? Yes, because `putStrLn` demands a `String`, we must have `a ~ String`. Thus, the `a` type variable in the definition of `exercise1` is not ambiguous.

For the other two exercises, there is no context you could put those types into that would allow you to infer the type of `a`. In exercise 2, that's fine - nobody needs to know what `a` is to use that function. But in exercise 3, `a` is needed to resolve the Show constraint, so it is
ambiguous.